# What equation will search the closest match for TWO number in adjacent cells?

Tags: match

I have an equation working at the moment that will show what cell is the closest to an input value. I used an Index and Match equation to do this.

However I now want to find the closest match to a combination of adjacent cells. Once that is done I need to find out in what column/array those two numbers fall under. Does anyone know what sort of formula could achieve this? I have attached a photo to illustrate what I am trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define the closest.

One possible method is to using the following to calculate.
Assume you using excel

=C5/-67.7+D5/6071

Then you can calculate a new column, sort with this new column to find the closet rows.

You need to adjust your equation to make this valid for your data, above equation is only for example.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with this one as C2 and D2 are both text cells (x value and y value)

Comment: Do you know how to using excel equations?   Just add the picture to make this more clear.   You still need to adjust your equation, to let this mapping your data.